# semordnilap в українській

Tags: словники, статистика

в англійському вікісловникові є таке слово: [semordnilap](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/semordnilap), що значить "слово, словосполучення, речення, що формує інше слово, словосполучення, речення, якщо читати ззаду-наперед. наприклад: top ↔ pot, live ↔ evil, desserts ↔ stressed

тут ще багато прикладів: https://listcaboodle.com/semordnilap-definition-list-of-examples-fun-facts/.

в український не можу знайти такого поняття. найближче це *анаграма*, що охоплює ширшу множину слів. гадаю можна запозичити метод формування слова і назвати *морднілап*. такі у нас є приклади:

- так ↔ кат
- прес ↔ серп
- удар ↔ раду
- вид ↔ див

збираю такі приклади, але не можу згадати чи знайти слова більш ніж 4 букви.
поділіться, будь ласка, своїми знахідками особливо якщо слова довші ніж 4 букви.

Comment: Ґрак це що? словник українських слів доступний десь одним файлом онлайн? я шукав щось таке не знайшов. був би список хоча б на 100 тисяч українських слів в одному файлі, тоді було б круто.

Comment: клас, дякую :) багато правда неіснуючих слів типо "акизіф" ("фізика"),

Answer (score 2):

Просто брати звичний словник за джерело не варіянт, бо враховуємо також гинші відмінки: *удар* – *раду*, де друге, очевидно, від *рада*.

Тому спершу спробував через [ҐРАК](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%96%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE_%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81_%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%97_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8). Брав з корпуса [весь список](//parasol.vmguest.uni-jena.de/grac_crystal/) слів, після декотрих операцій отримав [таке](//gist.github.com/20ee784ce14d660cf04dd95f30e64882#file-w-s-s-grac). Як можна побачити, чимало незрозумілих слів чи неіснуючих — неможливо або надто складно належно відфілтерувати від несловникових слів: записи чужою мовою, нечинним правописом чи з помилками, належність абревіятур, волосних назов, нетіпових записів ітд. Тобто потребує додаткового опрацювання, переважно ручного, що бере додатковий час…

---

На щастя, є [ВЕСУМ](//r2u.org.ua/vesum/), котрий в цему планї охайнїший і [дозволяє](//github.com/brown-uk/dict_uk) легше опрацювати набір слів.

Після декотрих [операцій](//gist.github.com/20ee784ce14d660cf04dd95f30e64882), отримав [таке](//gist.github.com/20ee784ce14d660cf04dd95f30e64882#file-w-s-s-vesum). Для прикладу, **найдовшим морднілапом**, що з девяти буков, є ***мононитка*** і ***актиноном***, що від [*актинон*](//goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A2%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F/%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BD). Ось з вісьмома:

```
виноробу уборонив
вирового оговорив
мирового оговорим
```

І ще трохи статістіки:

| Довжина | Рядків | Слів |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 12 | 24 |
| 3 | 158 | 316 |
| 4 | 217 | 434 |
| 5 | 252 | 504 |
| 6 | 89 | 178 |
| 7 | 37 | 74 |
| 8 | 3 | 6 |
| 9 | 1 | 2 |

Ручного опрацювання не робив, але помітно, що цего треба вже значно менше.

---

Аби повторити мій резултат, розкажу про одну операцію, що прискорює опрацювання і котру треба знати — відфілтери:

1. Слово не має бути самим собою, тобто слово не має бути паліндромом.
2. Слово не має бути…

   ```
   ignore = {   # https://github.com/brown-uk/dict_uk/blob/master/doc/tags.txt
     "abbr",    # абревіярута
     "alt",     # алтернатіний правопис
     "bad",     # помилково писано
     "foreign", # невизначена явна запозика
     "intj",    # вигук
     "prop",    # волосна назва
   }
   ```
3. Декотрі сполуки неможливі.

   ```
   "[А-ЩЬЮЯҐЄІЇ]",   # великі букви, зазвичай це волосні назви,
                       абревіятури чи щось незвичне
   "ь[^дтзсцлн]",    # /ь/ буває лише після певних буков, отримати /ьо/
                       в такій умові неможливо, бо /оь/ не буває.
   "[аеиуі]й|чш",    # такі сполукі неможливі¹
   "['.]|[-ь]$",     # <'> після йотованих або починатися з /-/ чи /ь/
   "ї[^аяеєиуюіїо]", # не буває /ї/ після приголосних без апострофа,
                       лише в декотрих старих правописах

   ¹ декотрі з їх насправдї можливі, а саме коли префікс /най/, 
     але єго неможливо отримати з /йан/, бо такого не буває,
     хиба що в декотрих старих правописах.
   ```

---

*Очевидно, мова, пак словник — мінлива штука, тому відповідь не є сталою. Однак, можна вважати суто як науковою чи як там зацїкавленістю*.

Comment: В 3-му пункті regex? Якщо так, то це не сайт для програмістів. Тому розпишіть "по-українськи"

Comment: @stkuser там ж розписано…